# How do i get right the directory of my application?

Tags: c#, console, directory, publish, appdata

I've made a small console application (first publish in c#). but i cant use my resource files. I used textfiles can give it. It worked when i used the debug directory

My goal is to create a directory like this:
Applicationmap
+ application.exe
+ setup
resource map
+ configurations.txt
Logger
+ .

Now if i try to reach the configuration file it sends me to:
`C:\Users\<username> \AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\D01L7N51.9EW\R7HB7NAB.B7Y
\sele..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_92af5262ce6f49d8`

While i'm expecting `C:/Users/<username>/ Documents/<application>/ + resources/config.txt`.

I've tried

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

&&

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

&&

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

but i always end up at the appdata map.

Comment: Where is your application running from (what folder)?

Comment: @mjwills The application is published in to the mydocuments map, but i want to make it possible to place it anywhere, so to access the txt files i'm trying reach the application folder.
I think it's "running" in the appdata folder somewhere tho. (i have no experience with c# publishing yet). i don't know if i can, or how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `Application.StartupPath` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)), but the outcome will always depend on where you place/install the executable file

If you always want to point the current user's `Documents` folder (which is registered as a special folder within the operating system), like in your example, you could either use:

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

or (but at your own risk since its much less safe):

```
String path = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%"), "Documents");
```

Once you have retrieved the correct `Documents` folder path with either the first or the second approach, combine it with the last part:

```
path = Path.Combine(path, "resources/config.txt");
```

For more information concerning the two approaches:

- [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)
- [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

Comment: Application.StartupPath only works for forms applications :/
Not for console. 

The other options are very helpfull thanks. I wanted to make the application easy accessible (sinse the user needs to provide the txt files.) so it is possible with these codes but i thought it would be "fool safer" if i could let the users place there txt config files in the application folder (so they can move it anywhere(desktop/documents/subfolders ect)

Comment: I think the first option(s) is the best one. Glad to be helpful. If you think my answered solved your problem, please mark it as accepted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: ExecutablePath doesnt work for console applications :(